# Using any buffer to store any data, with placement new and memcpy

Tags: c++

It is a while now that I am reading documentation about alignment, aliasing, padding, and placement new, but still I am not sure about how to solve this problem - it is the first time I face a memory issue on this level, so I am not confident.

The problem is: I have a buffer, an array of data, which uses some type `typeT`, e.g.

```
typeT buff[N];
```

Inside that buffer, I have to store some other data, of type `typeU`, at the beginning of `buff`. Let's assume to have `K` elements of `typeU`, which is less or equal to `M` elements of type `typeT`.

EDIT: This problem depends on the data type, but my question is generic, and hold for POD and non-POD. But you can assume that non-POD is just an aggregation of POD types, there is no dynamic memory to be copied and all the data is contained inside the `sizeof(typeX)` bytes of the structure itself. That is, *do not worry about deep/shallow copying*.

I am mostly interested in the case where `typeT` and `typeU` have different alignments. Which alignment size is bigger is not known.

**Question 1**: (most important question) is it *always* safe to use placement new for storing my data on `buff`, considering the fact that I will *always* access to those data using typeU, like in the following code?

```
typeU *allocData = new (buff) typeU[K];
allocData[0] = foo;
```

**Question 2**: is it *always* safe to copy any data from `typeU*` inside a buffer of type `typeT*` using `memcpy`, given that I will always access the data using `typeU*`, like in the following code?

```
typeU prevData[K];
memcpy(buff, prevData, sizeof(typeU) * K);
// Is it safe to do the following?
typeU *accessData = reinterpret_cast<typeU *>(buff);
accessData[1] = foo;
```

**Question 3**: (least important question) is it true that it is not always safe to just cast pointers and write the data using those? Like in

```
typeU *castData = (typeU*)buff;
castData[2] = something;
```

even if I always use the first region of memory (first M elements) using `typeU` and the second region (elements from M to N) using `typeT`?

I hope it is clear what I mean... I searched a lot, but I am still confused.

Also, please consider I am talking about a C++98 or 03, not 11, with a minimal subset of STL, no boost and not always on x86 - but I can use memcpy and placement new, as I said.

Comment: If `typeT` is a simple type it should be safe, if `typeT` is a complex type with a constructor etc then you could easily run into problems.

Comment: In practice it depends on the size and alignment of `typeT` and `typeU`.  This has not been constrained in your post.

Comment: If you want to have two arrays consecutive why not use `struct S { typeU u[M]; typeT t[N]; }`.

Comment: @user1131467 because the typeT array is constrained and I have to use it. Anyway, the question was deliberately vague about what kind of data to use: I will add this info at the end of the question to be (a little) more precise.

Comment: @JonathanPotter yes, the question is "should be safe" or "it is always safe"? And if it is not always, when will it break?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provided that the size and alignment requirements of `typeT` and `typeU` are identical, you can use uninitialized storage allocated for `typeT` to hold a value of `typeU`.

If `typeT` and/or `typeU` have constructors or destructors, you must ensure that they are called appropriately, and in the right order.

```
static_assert(sizeof(typeT) == sizeof(typeU))
static_assert(alignof(typeT) == alignof(typeU))

typeT t[10];

&t[0]->~typeT(); // placement delete t[0] to uninitialize
typeU* p = &t[0];
new (p) typeU(); // construct typeU at t[0]

typeU u& = *p;

u.doStuff();

p->~typeU(); // placement delete typeU at t[0]

new (&t[0]) typeT(); // reconstruct typeT at t[0]
```

Comment: Ok, this is easy, and what about the case they do not have the same alignment? Take, for example, `typeT = short` and `typeU = double`... What do I do in that case?

Comment: The size and alignment of `short` and `double` vary depending on the platform.  Based on the size and alignment you will need to calculate which elements of the short array will be occupied, and what memory location to place the double elements over them.  I must say your situation is a little unusual, perhaps you are missing a solution because you have over-restricted your question.  Perhaps if you ask another question describing the larger problem you are facing, a cleaner solution can be offered.

Comment: Yes, I am indeed looking for a general strategy to tackle this kind of problems, this is why I have been pretty generic about the data type used. Just trying to learn how this kind of memory management shall be done, and which is the proper, *always safe* way to copy data of one type inside a buffer of another type. After reading about these issues, it seemed that memcpy was the only valid solution as it passed the data using `char *`, which is the least restricted type for alignment.

Comment: @AkiRoss: I don't think you understand alignment.  Each type T has an alignment.  The memory address that it is allocated at must be an even factor of this alignment.  If you try to use an object at a misaligned address, the behaviour is undefined.

Comment: Yes, I knew that ;) Why do you say I did not understand alignment? Afaik, `char` has 8-bit alignment and this is why I can use `char*` to access any byte in memory (assuming memory allow byte addressing). Other types may have different alignment, and this is why I think `memcpy` (which I think works at byte level) can be used to copy data safely, but... The question was about this :)

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered this [article by Sutter](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill05.htm) which introduces something I didn't knew

> Any memory that's allocated dynamically via new or malloc is
>   guaranteed to be properly aligned for objects of any type, but buffers
>   that are not allocated dynamically have no such guarantee

This means, first of all, that doing like I was doing is wrong:

```
typeT buff[N];
new (buff) typeU[K];
```

Because buff is not allocated dynamically, so there is no guarantee.

So, the point is: to do this kind of handling, memory has to be dynamically allocated. If it is not, the answer depends on the alignment.